# Lombok set default value when an attribute is explicity set to null by builder

Tags: lombok

I am using the new ***Builder.Default*** feature of Lombok version 1.16.16.
I would like to configure a class such that an attribute takes a default value if the attribute is not explicitly set via the builder, or if the attribute is set to null by the builder.

Case 1: Attribute is not set

> MyClass.Builder().build();

Case 2: Attribute is set to null

> MyClass.Builder().myAttribute(null).build();

In both cases I want a default value to be set. The background is that the class will be built based on the results of a database query.

Below is the annotated class

```html
@Builder
@NonFinal
public class MyClass {

 @Builder.Default
 private String myAttribute = "-";

}
```

Is there any way to configure the class such that attributes are set to a default value even if explicitly set to null (Case 2)?

Answer (score 3):

No, `lombok` will not help you there. You set the `value` to `null`, then this `attribute` will be `null`.

It's a good idea to look at the generated `class` so you can understand how `lombok` works.

One workaround come to my mind.
`lombok` uses `all-args-constructor` to create you class from the `BuilderClass`.

So, I think if you create the `constructor` by your self and add your logic by checking if this value is null then use the default.